# Book for Desktop Java programming

Tags: java

I have some knowledge how to program Java Server Faces application but now I need to learn desktop applications with Java. Can you recommend me some books specialized for Desktop programming, please.

Comment: http://www.lulu.com/shop/scott-delap/desktop-java-live/paperback/product-190467.html;jsessionid=4158635FEBE13DC2D800274EEDE64C35 I just started reading this one and according to the reviews it's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one may help you i found it useful

[Beginning Java SE 6 Platform: From Novice to Professional](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=emcgAeq_oXgC&pg=PA80&dq=java%20desktop%20applications&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WqdmUcPGNuKL0AW9woGICQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=java%20desktop%20applications&f=false)